# What does "fig" mean in "showing the fig"?

Tags: meaning

From [Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sycophant&searchmode=none)

> "Showing the fig" was a vulgar gesture made by sticking the thumb between two fingers, a display which vaguely resembles a fig, itself symbolic of a vagina (sykon also meant "vulva").

What does "fig" mean in "showing the fig"? I looked up the dictionaries, which say either a kind of fruit or nothing, which doesn't fit the context.

Comment: It means the edible fruit ... why do you reject this meaning?

Comment: How is the fruit related to the vulgar gesture?

Comment: Tim: Supposedly, [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rw5z5.png) looks like  a fig for some reason. I'll have to take their word for it.

Comment: @J.R.: What does a fig looks like? How does it look like vagina?

Comment: [Figs?](http://www.google.com/search?safe=off&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1275&bih=876&q=figs&oq=figs&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1068.1460.0.1904.4.4.0.0.0.0.114.393.3j1.4.0....0...1ac.1.30.img..0.4.391.qPGeLdKWYGo) Whole, or split? Dried, or off the tree? I suppose the hand gesture does resemble [these](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Figs_(Closeup).jpeg)...

Comment: @TheMathemagician: Please tell me directly. A split fig resembles vagina, but the gesture doesn't look like a vagina, does it? The gesture doesn't look like a whole or split fig, does it?

Comment: For goodness sake Tim, the gesture is obviously meant to be a penis entering a vagina. The 'fig' was the vagina as explained in the definition.

Comment: It is of course not the vagina but the vulva which is represented by the fist, and name evokes the image of a [fig which has split open](http://figs4fun.com/fpix/FP956-97.jpg). And as TheMathemagician says, the thumb represents the penis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is parse the excerpt from etymonline, and use your imagination:

[image]